# Performing a signed test on two samples

Tags: statistics

Here is the problem [image]

My book hardly has anything about performing a sign test so I am a bit lost. Basically I know that I am testing $H_a: \mu_{13}\leq\mu_6$ vs $H_0:\mu_{13}>\mu_6$ at a level of $\alpha=.05$. I need to find the p-value for this which is what I am having trouble with. So if I subtract the data in Friday the 6th from the data in the Friday the 13th, I get 5 negatives and 1 positive. Therefore would the P-value just be $P(X\leq 1)={6\choose 0}.5^6+{6\choose 1}.5^6=.1093$. Since the pvalue is greater than $\alpha$ we conclude $H_o$. Would this be right? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no difference then the number of positive values (13th minus 6th) should have a $Binom(0.5,6)$ distribution. Since this a one-sided test, you need to find:

$$x:\sum_{i=x}^6Bin(i;0.5,6)\leq 0.05$$

If the number of positive results is at or above $x$, then you can reject at $0.05$

Comment: Oh then I think it was $P(X\geq 5)$ I think? I think the rejection if we let $X$ be the number of positive values then we reject $H_0$ if $P(X\geq x)|<\alpha$ since we are testing $H_a: p>\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @user60887 yes, but you're testing $\mu_{13}\leq\mu_6$

Comment: @user60887 its just that if you assume equality, then it equates to $p>1/2$

Comment: Oh yeah I mean to say that I should be testing $\mu_6 <\mu_{13}$ under $H_a$. Thus I see that there are supposed to be 5 positives and 1 negative.Is that what I had wrong in the first place?

Comment: @user60887 yep...you had your hypotheses switched. If you expect more accidents on the 13th, then if you subtract the 6th from the 13th, you would reject if you got too many positives, since that would be evidence *against* the null hypothesis that $\mu_{13}\leq \mu_6$

Comment: @user60887 so, that means that $x=5$ positives out of $6$ trials is your cutoff, which is not reached, so you fail to reject.